# Easy way to convert a time (ex. 1:00, 3:45) to a int/float?

Tags: python, time, data-conversion

Best way to convert a string (like 1:00, 3:45) to a float? I'm planning on use this (see below) code to calculate the time for a runner's 2 and 3 mile times but I need to first convert a string into an int or float to be able to use it in these calculations.

```py
twoMileTimes=[]
threeMileTimes=[]
for i in range(len(runnerNames)):
    twoMileTimes.append(round(twoMileMark[i]-oneMileMark[i],2))
    threeMileTime = fiveKMark[i]*(3/3.1)
    threeMileTime -= twoMileMark[i]
    threeMileTimes.append(round(threeMileTime,2))
```

Comment: If the input is `3:45`, what should the result be? By what logic?

Comment: so 45 seconds is 75% of a minute so `3:45` should become `3.75` although I did just realize that you can divide the seconds by 60, cause I guess I wasn't thinking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting time to a float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043841/converting-time-to-a-float)

Comment: @GinoMempin I ended finding a solution already (just dividing `seconds` by 60 but have now run into another error with my code which I can't seem to figure out. (In the now edited post)

Comment: If you have a **NEW** question, then ask a **NEW** question. **Do not edit or revise the original** because that would invalidate the comments and the existing answer/s (which still refer to the original question of converting time to float).

Comment: Got it, making a new question right now.
Can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002703/using-exec-to-define-a-variable-raises-an-nameerror-when-referencing-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> s = "3:45"
>>> a, b = map(int, s.split(":"))
>>> a
3
>>> b
45
>>> b = b / 60
>>> b
0.75
>>> res = round(a + b, 2)
>>> res
3.75
>>>
```